# How does adding a (500x5000) and (5000x1) matrix result in a (500x5000) matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I am following a tutorial in an iPython notebook. My intention is calculating (X^2 - X_train)^2, storing the result in dists. The following code seems to work. I don't understand how it works however.

Why does (2*inner_prod + train_sum) which adds differently-sized matrices yield a 500x5000 matrix?

How are the matrices processed in the calculation of dist?

```
    test_sum = np.sum(np.square(X), axis=1) # summed each example #(500x1)
    train_sum = np.sum(np.square(self.X_train), axis=1) # summed each example #(5000x1)
    inner_prod = np.dot(X, self.X_train.T) #matrix multiplication for 2-D arrays (500x3072)*(3072x5000)=(500x5000)
    print inner_prod.shape
    print X.shape
    print self.X_train.T.shape
    print test_sum.shape
    print test_sum.size
    print train_sum.shape
    print train_sum.size
    print test_sum.reshape(-1,1).shape
    # how... does reshaping work???
    print (2*inner_prod+train_sum).shape
    dists = np.sqrt(np.reshape(test_sum,(-1,1)) - 2 * inner_prod + train_sum) # (500x1) - 2*(500x5000) + (5000x1) = (500x5000)
    print dists.shape
```

The print statements give the following:

```
(500L, 5000L)
(500L, 3072L)
(3072L, 5000L)
(500L,)
500
(5000L,)
5000
(500L, 1L)
(500L, 5000L)
(500L, 5000L)
```

Comment: I don't have a formal answer for what exactly is happening, but I believe you're seeing the effects of Numpy's broadcasting. Maybe take a look here for some explanation/examples http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/broadcasting-arrays-in-numpy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print train_sum.shape           # (5000,)
print train_sum.size
print test_sum.reshape(-1,1).shape    # (5000,1)
# how... does reshaping work???
print (2*inner_prod+train_sum).shape
```

`test_sum.reshape(-1,1)` returns as new array with a new shape (but shared data).  It does not reshape `test_sum` itself.

So the addition broadcasting does:

```
(500,5000) + (5000,) => (500,5000)+(1,5000)=>(500,5000)
```

If it had done the reshape, you'd have gotten an error.

```
(500,5000) + (5000,1) => error

In [68]: np.ones((500,5000))+np.zeros((5000,1))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,5000) (5000,1)
```

There's really only one way to add that (500,5000) array and the (5000,) one, and that's what you got without (effective) reshape.

`train_sum.shape = (-1,1)` acts  in place, but isn't used as often as `reshape`.  Stick with the reshape, but use it right.